# Set contains and object equal

Tags: java, set, equals

I don't understand why contains() on the HashSet returns false in the following example:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class MyMatching {

    private Integer[] id;

    public MyMatching(Integer id1, Integer id2) {
        this.id = new Integer[2];
        id[0] = id1;
        id[1] = id2;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id[0] + ":" + id[1];
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (this == other)
            return true;
        if (other == null || (this.getClass() != other.getClass())) {
            return false;
        }
        MyMatching otherMatching = (MyMatching) other;
        return (getId().equals(otherMatching.getId()));
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 31 * id.hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyMatching matching1 = new MyMatching(1571021585, 848339230);
        MyMatching matching2 = new MyMatching(661883516, 310961952);
        Set<MyMatching> matchings = new HashSet<>();
        matchings.add(matching1);
        matchings.add(matching2);

        MyMatching testMatching = new MyMatching(1571021585, 848339230);
        System.out.print("HashSet contains testMatching: ");
        System.out.println(matchings.contains(testMatching));

        Object[] matchingsArray = matchings.toArray();
        for (Object o : matchingsArray) {
            System.out.print("Object equals testMatching: ");
            System.out.println(o.equals(testMatching));
        }
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
HashSet contains testMatching: false
Object equals testMatching: false
Object equals testMatching: true
```

The documentation of [Set's contain method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) is:

> Returns true if this set contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if > and only if this set contains an element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

My question: Why does contains() retuns false on the Set, but equals() returns true on the objects?

Comment: Ah that's clear. I had to open my eyes... :)
Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I was wrong my friend, sorry for misleading you. Ignore my last comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your implementation of `hashCode` is not consistent with `equals`: `id` is an array, and it doesn't compute a hash code based on the values held in the array.

For a correct implementation you could return the hash code of the generated ID string instead:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return getId().hashCode();
}
```

Or you could compute the hash code based on the array values directly, for example with:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return id[0] ^ id[1];
}
```

Comment: But still.. He shouldn't use `contains` to check if a `HashSet` includes another `HashSet`. Or I'm missing something here?

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun Where is doing this?

Comment: I misunderstood his code, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Can you explain why `id.hashCode()` doesn't work? I was also investigating this path, but the implementation of `hashCode` for an array of objects and for `Integer` make that that hash code should only depend on the values in the array, which are the same... I would expect that the hash codes are also the same in that case.

Comment: @Heuster This part: "and for Integer make that that hash code should only depend on the values in the array, which are the same". Can you point us to some reference confirming your statement. Where did you learn this? If you write a simple example, you will see it is false.

Comment: Arrays inherit their `hashCode` implementation from the Object class, which tries to generate a unique hash code for each object.

Comment: @peter.petrov I already see where I went wrong. `id.hashCode()` does not return the same value as `Arrays.hashCode(id)`. The first is the hash code as defined in `Object` (based on the address), the latter is a hash code based on the array *contents*.